# Flex 4: Fetch dataField from DataGridColumn

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4

I have the following datagrid:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="question" x="9" y="289" width="100%" height="54" visible="{false}" >
    <mx:columns>            
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="ans1" headerText="ans1"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="ans2" headerText="ans2"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="ans3" headerText="ans3"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="ans4" headerText="ans4"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

I need to access the data pointed by the dataField, and bind it to a label, but i don't known how to get it.

```
<s:Label id="debug" x="575" y="106" width="56" height="35" text="{data_from_coloumn_grid_ans1}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be looking at the `DataGrid` for the value. You should get the value from the `dataProvider` of the `DataGrid`.

**Quick Example:**

```
<mx:DataGrid id="question" dataProvider="{myArrayCollection}" x="9" y="289" width="100%" height="54" visible="{false}" >
    <mx:columns>            
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="ans1" headerText="ans1"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="ans2" headerText="ans2"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="ans3" headerText="ans3"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="ans4" headerText="ans4"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>

<s:Label id="debug" x="575" y="106" width="56" height="35" text="{myArrayCollection.ans1}" />
```